# Raphael Rectangle Tooltip

Tags: raphael

I am drawing series of rectangle using the following code in a loop

```
paper.rect(((x) * cellSize), ((y) * cellSize), cellSize, cellSize).attr({ fill: rgbx, stroke: rgbx });
```

Is there a way show tooltip on those rectangle? Is there a library that can show ballon tooltip (fadding)

I found similar question but not sure it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Raphael plugin for tooltips: http://www.strathausen.eu/en/2010/04/25/raphael-svg-tooltip/

Although it mentiones SVG explicitly, it should work just fine on IE (VML backend) as well.

Comment: I tried but it draws some rectangel around, can I pass a string to show up in the tooltip.

Comment: You pass the tooltip element to the plugin. In the example, a rectangle is passed. Instead, you can pass `paper.text(...)`, or devise more elaborate tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `title` attribute.

`element.attr({title: 'The tooltip to be displayed on mouse hover'});`